# Python: Appending to multiple lists from function return

Tags: python

I'm looking for a pythonic way to to append to several lists from a tuple returned by a function.

So turning this:

```
def f():
  return (1,2)

a = []
b = []
for c in container:
  r1, r2 = f()
  a += [r1]
  b += [r1]
```

Into something like:

```
for c in container:
  a, b += f()
```

My code is a bit more complicated (does several operations inside the loop), and I have a version using zip and list comprehension, but it's a bit unreadable:

```
list1, list2, list3 = zip (*[
           c( list(img.to(devices[i]) for img in images),
              features[i],
              [{k: v.to(devices[i]) for k, v in t.items()} for t in targets]
            )
            for i, c in enumerate(container)
        ])
```

If I can turn the list comprehension into a regular for and have a compact way of appending, I think readability would improve a lot.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for something like this:

```
def f():
  return (1,2)

a = []
b = []
for c in container:
  r1, r2 = f()
  a += [r1]
  b += [r1]
```

Put your target lists *in another list* then use `zip` to iterate over than and the corresponding result:

```
accumulators = [a, b]
for c in container:
    for acc, result in zip(accumulators, f()):
        acc.append(result) # NOT acc += [result]
```

You are right, this giant, nested list comprehension is totally unreadable. You are abusing `zip` here too. This little trick is sometimes ok, but in this case, it just obscures what's going on. You should be using `zip` to iterate over several iterables at the same time, don't use an `i` index to do that. Use temporary variables to hold your intermediate results, I called them `arg1` and `arg3` but use a descriptive name for your use-case. Look how much cleaner this is, you can easily follow what's going on:

```
accumulators = [list1, list2, list3]
for container, device feature in zip(containers, devices, features):

    arg1 = [img.to(device) for img in images]
    arg3 = [{k: v.to(device)} for k,v in t.items()} for t in targets]
    results = container(arg1, feature, arg2)

    for accumulator, result in zip(accumulators, results):
        accumulator.append(result)
```

Comment: Thanks!, I ended up using a very similar solution, but I had ```accumulators = [[], [], []]``` at the beginning of the to define the lists and "unpacked" them after the loop ```list1, list2, list3 = proposals```